# how to turn off session persistence in geronimo/tomcat

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, tomcat, geronimo

How can I turn off session persistence for geronimo? Is this something I should be doing? - I have no use for persisted sessions in my application. (This is because I recieve a not serializable error in my console, but I do not wish to serialize)

Comment: no answers yet - anyone?

Comment: I have found this link for WAS which is similar to geronimo.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V2.1.1/en/configuring-session-manager.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends upon which web container you're using within Geronimo; both Tomcat and Jetty are supported.

**Tomcat** 

Add a context.xml file to your application or add these nodes:

```
<Context><Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager"
  pathname=""></Manager></Context>
```

From the tomcat docs for pathname: *Restart persistence may be disabled by setting this attribute to an empty string.*

The properties are explained at these links:

https://cwiki.apache.org/GMOxDOC22/configuring-session-manager-of-tomcat.html

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html#Standard_Implementation

**Jetty**

This container does not persist sessions by default, so there there is nothing to do except to make sure that the *SessionHandler* is not enabled. Remove the *sessionHandler* node if it exists in your context configuration.

```
<Set name="sessionHandler">
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager">
      <Set name="storeDirectory">your/chosen/directory/goes/here</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New></Set>
```

Informational link:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Persisting_Sessions

Comment: This answer has auto-completed. I added a context.xml to my web module and it does not work.

Comment: So I assume your web container is Tomcat then? Is your context.xml in the correct location? yourapp/META-INF/context.xml

Comment: You may have to set the attribute override="true" on the node

Comment: Even simpler, `<Context><Manager pathname="" /></Context>` will do.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for tomcat is depicted in http://www.unicon.net/node/608 and it works like a charm for us.
But I don't know if this also applies to geronimo since we are not using it.

Comment: This cannot be done in geronimo, there is no server.xml I believe it's done in the geronimo-application.xml

Comment: Your link now leads to an error page, please update.